# Why can I not get a JSON file from the local network using a XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, json, web-services

I have found that many had similar problem:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load %3192.168.100.201:8080/history?_=1400139870373. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

I have tried to start the browser like:

```
--disable-web-security
--allow-file-access-from-files
```

How can I get the JSON file from server on local network?

---

Update

JS code:

```
function getHistory() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '192.168.100.201:8080/history',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data); 
            },
            cache: false
        });
     }
```

Comment: It is forbidden in modern browsers. In older browsers it does work. To get around you should write some server-side code to return the file and call that with the JavaScript.

Comment: What if i request from a php file which returns the same json from server on local network?
shortly: js requests json from local php > php requests json from server

Comment: those answers does not help. Also I get json from another machine on local network, not same machine. So the accepted answer does not help, and the second answer is mentioned in my question.

Comment: @FilipLuch: Are you sure? You still need to specify a valid URL. Have you tried that? `192.168.100.201:8080/history` does not look like a valid `http://` URL. the solution on the other post suggests the use of a valid URL. I would assume your issue is solved the same way by having a valid `http://xx` URL?

Comment: I updated the question, you can see the actual URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

This is because you forgot `http://` in your request:

```
url: 'http://192.168.100.201:8080/history',
```

- The browser does not know what protocol you want.

You should also send an access control header (read about Cors [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)]) from the targeted serverside:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://<requesting host>
```

Not a must in every case, but a good practice and security feature by modern browsers.

[[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Thanks. This worked. At first i got `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` and then changed the server side as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181384/javascript-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested/22182390#22182390