# Error in making get request in IPython Notebook using javascript?

Tags: jquery, ajax, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML,display
HTML('''
<script>
    $.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
    // do something
    });
</script>
''')
```

The error output in console is: 
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4040/api/v1/applications/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181384/javascript-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)