# Python Flask - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, flask

i get this error when loading a json file :

Failed to load http://localhost/sandbox/data.json?_=1505732125859: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5000' is therefore not allowed access.

```
#...
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Tried this solution.. but still getting same error [Javascript - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181384/javascript-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested)

Comment: Is that python code running on `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:5000`?

Comment: yes python code is running...output is stored in json file.. when accessing that json using jquery. getting this error

Comment: I was expecting your answer to be "`http://localhost`" or `"http://localhost:5000`". "Yes" doesn't help me help you!

Comment: running on "http://localhost:5000".

Answer (score 3):

You've set the CORS permissions on the wrong server.

A webpage on `http://localhost:5000` is making a request to `http://localhost`.

Your headers are granting permission to every site (`*`) to access the data on `http://localhost:5000`, but you are trying to access the data on `http://localhost`.

You need to set the CORS permissions on `http://localhost` instead.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666) explains the background.