# How to fix the cross platform issue in the python

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, python-2.7, postman

I am using Python as backend server & AJAX + HTML for the frontend. when I call my API using postman, it's working fine but giving the CORS issue when I hit from the browser. After adding the flask's CORS library still, I am getting the following error.

- CORS header 'Access-control-allow-origin' missing.
- Please find the following method for your reference :

```
def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument("age")
        parser.add_argument("occupation")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        result = request.get_json()
        name = result['name']       
        password = result['password']

        mycursor = mydb.cursor()

        query = ("select * from Farmer where Farmer_Username = '" + name + "' and Farmer_Password = '" + password + "';")
        print(query)
        mycursor.execute(query)  

        myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
        print(myresult)
        if myresult:
            return "Following user exists - '" + name, 200
        else:
            return "Following user doesn't exists - '" + name, 201
```

is there anything I need to add here to resolve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding your front end part, AJAX & HTML, are you opening it in browser from file path or http? e.g /home/user/something or localhost?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, we used the HTML forms & calling API using the localhost link

Comment: Can you please share the URL of the HTML page?

Comment: Yes .. We added the following URL inside the 'action' property of the <form> tab.   "http://127.0.0.1:5000/userIdValidation"

Comment: Following link might help you. Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181384/javascript-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested